# San Disk Extreme 1TB SSD (1050Mb/s) taking up 10 times more storage than actual size

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

Just got a Sand Disk Extreme SSD, intially this 14gb filled the SSD to full, formatted it on windows with default allocation size and exFat format, still did the same.

Then formatted it on MacOS and now 14.89GB is taking up 125GB of storage.

I want to keep using exFat or similar format which can be used on Windows and Mac both, but ensure that the allocation size is not filling up the whole disk, preferably exFat.

Attached the image of the info of that folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small files, you need to be careful about how efficiently the file system store them.  For example, for a 1kb file, what if it is taking up the minimum block size of 32kb or 64kb?

And when you have thousand of these files, it can affect your storage capability in a big way.

So you need to do some research as to what file system can do the best for your case, and also, would you zip up the small files into one big file?  Usually, if you have many big files (such as 500MB or 1GB or larger), then 32k or 64k block size is not going to affect you that much.

Comment: yeah, my files are mostly code files with libraries and modules, finally decided to get Tuxera Microsoft NTFS and formatted the disk with NTFS, hopefully that sorts this issue